# Eclipselink Batch vs fetch-join reading in Fetch Groups is this possible?

Tags: jpa, data-binding, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, criteria

I have a situation whereby I would like to create a query against an entity using EclipsLink JPA, I require 5 fields from this entity of which it has many. 2 of those fields are joined OneToMany relationships. I only require 2 primitive fields from each of the joins.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

I've considered a number of possiblities, batch reading seems the best bet based on what I have read however I believe this will only work if I retrieve the full entity i.e. SELECT a FROM Entity a... and the reason I don't want to do this is I have LOB and BLOB types that will eat dangerously into the memory.

Join-fetch is another but the entity has ~10 joined tables and I don't want to duplicate all of this data.

I have been using fetch groups (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/AttributeGroup) and specifying the fields I want which causes cached lazing loading. This is workable and the memory footprint is better. The issue is though when I do entity.getCollection() it must do a single SQL statement for each call and this is where I feel it is inefficient. If I could do SELECT a.Field, a.Field2 from Entity A using some form of batching or join-fetching or better still apply this to my fetch group this would be best I would imagine but not sure if I could ensure that it would not load all related tables and only give me the ones I want.

Help/thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think batch fetching with also work with nested fetch groups, did you try this?

You can also set a defaultFetchGroup on your FetchGroupManager (either directly or by adding fetch=LAZY to your fields you do not want in your fetch group, i.e. add fetch=LAZY to your LOB fields).